# Вставить контакты на сайте через API Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Что есть: Joomla, Созданные контакты в компонентах
Что нужно: на странице разместить контакты, телефоны, адреса,карты и только одну форму обратной связи по своему шаблону
Что не выходит: в контактах и формах связи много лишней информации
И еще: не могу найти вменяемую документацию по API Joomla, что бы решить эту проблему руками.

Comment: Ничего сложного, вам надо редактировать файл в components\com_contact\views\contact\tmpl\default.php, там включаются по отдельности контактные данные и форма.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую. Может подскажете документацию, можно на английском. У самой Joomla есть, но она такая хреновая...

Comment: Попробовал. Это не совсем то. Это правка не в шаблоне. А нужно, например, сделать материал "Контакты" и вывести туда форму с 4-мя полями обратной связи и двумя контактами: адрес, телефоны, карты. И все это в нужном мне виде. Я та понимаю есть какие-то классы в API которыми можно выцепить необходимые данные и вставить их в материал.

Comment: Контакты - это компонент, как вы можете её включить в материал? никак... Если вам надо получить совмещение статьи(материала) и контактной формы можете установить новый модуль с контактной формой и инклудить в статью и работать уже в модуле.

Comment: Понятно. Еще раз надоем:) По докуиентации на API все-таки что-нибудь вменяемое есть?

Comment: У Joomla Farmework хорошая документация но ваш случай с API никак не связан, ваш пример индивидуально-кастомный ))

Comment: По документации не соглашусь. Вот php.net - это хорошая документация. Есть функция и есть достаточно подробное описание. В Joomla -документации есть список классов но описания нет или практически нет. Либо я захожу не туда :)